# Value in props, using in mapState can not working Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I want to pass value from props and using it as the **namespace** in mapState, then it show error: 'Error while initializing app TypeError: Cannot read property 'store' of undefined'
Here my code:

ParentComponent: `<Editor store="store-test" />`

ChildComponent:

```
export default {
    props: ['store'],
    computed: {
        mapState(`${this.store}`, ['data'])
    }
}
```

But i replace `this.store = store-test`, i have receive data i want. 
And i dont know how to using

```
...mapMutations({
  function() {
  }
})
```

is same

```
...mapState({
  data(state) {
    return state[this.store].data;
  },
})
```

Comment: when i using: `...mapState('store-test', ['data'])`, i have receive: `data: []` in Vue-devtool,
but when replace `store-test` by `this.store`, it's fail

Comment: Ah, it's the **namespace** you're attempting to set. You can't do it this way as `mapState` returns its value at definition time but props only exist at runtime.

Comment: See the `mapMutations` API here ~ https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#mapmutations. FYI, you can use `mapMutations({ saveData (commit) { ... } })`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `mapState` returns its value for your `computed` definition at compile time, you cannot use `props` as they are only assigned at runtime.

You will have to use

```
computed: {
  data () {
    return this.$store.state[this.store].data
  }
}
```

---

If you want, you can still use `mapState` however you cannot use the prop value as a namespace string

```
mapState({
  data1 (state) { //  note: cannot be an arrow function
    return state[this.store].data1
  },
  data2 (state) {
    return state[this.store].data2
  }
})
```

Comment: but i want get more data from one store, could you have me? 
instead : `return this.$store.state[this.store].data,
return this.$store.state[this.store].data1
...`

Comment: For any state property that you need to access via a dynamic prop module name, you will have to do it this way.

Comment: @hieuphamba I've update my answer with an alternative that's not quite as verbose. Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, i can not using mapState with props is same u said above. But i don't want to using `this.$store.state[store].data` multiple. Thank you for your answer. I think i will using your answer update. Thank you! but i don't mark accept because i think your answer make me felling that resolve a question about 75% (bow)

Comment: i have a question for you, can u have me?

Comment: @hieuphamba if it's related to this post, please [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53844066/edit). If not, I suggest you open a new post